# Поиск одного слова в json строке, где строка состоит из нескольких слов

Tags: php, sql, laravel

В базе данных есть столбец с json строками, например:
["pervaya stroka","vtoraya stroka","tretya stroka"], я хочу сделать поиск по одному слову в строке, например ищу слово: 'vtoraya', соответственно должна находится строка: "vtoraya stroka".
В ларавел я ищу так : whereJsonContains('tags',$search_tag), но в этом случае нужно писать строку полностью: "vtoraya stroka", иначе поиск не дает результата.

Comment: ["stroki mogut bit na russkom esli shto)))"]

Comment: для данной задачи данные лучше нормализовать.

Comment: Парсим JSON на отдельные строки (JSON_TABLE), которые потом проверяются на соответствие шаблону.

Comment: к `laravel` еще не пришел но если писать на чистом `php` мне кажется что все равно придется делать массив строк и через итератор и функцию `str_contains()` находить нужное слово в строке. Не лучшее решение в плане производительности но это первое что приходит в голову

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы решить эту проблему, можете воспользоваться этим SQL-запросом. Запрос будет искать указанную подстроку, в данном случае `vtoraya`:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE column_name LIKE '%"vtoraya"%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, если нет какой-то необходимости, не стоит хранить JSON в БД. Самим потом тяжело будет с этим работать.

Во-вторых, коли вы уже так сделали, самый экологичный способ решения вашей проблемы только один - перебирать все записи таблицы, парсить JSON и искать нужное слово. Единственное, что может уменьшить нагрузку на сервер, это в условии выборки запроса проверять, что значение IS NOT NULL и CHAR_LINK(значение) > длина_значения